# Auto resize image to fit proportions but don't stretch

Tags: html, css

I want to resize an image based on screen size but I don't want that image to exceed its actuall pixels when screen is too big. 
So far I managed to do this

```
<div align="center" style="position:static; height: 100%; width: 100%; top:0;left 0;">
<img src="myImg.png" style="width: 80%">
</div>
```

This maintains the proportions I want but when Screen is too big it also stretches the image. I don't want that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The css for a responsive image is as follows:

```
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
```

This will make the image scale down with the size of its container, without exceeding the image's natural width.  However, using `width: 100%;` will force the image to be as wide as its container, regardless of the image's actual size.

A few other notes:

- `align="center"` is deprecated.  You should use css to align content, so `text-align: center;`.
- Using `position: static;` is unnecessary, as it is the default value for the position property.  The only time I can think of where you'd need to use this is if you need to override some other css.
- Unless you are absolute positioning your div (which you are not), then `top: 0; left: 0;` will do nothing.

Without seeing the rest of your code, I think this would be the best solution for what you are trying to accomplish:

```
    <div style="text-align: center;">
       <img src="myImg.png" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" alt="FYI, image alt text is required" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you also set a `max-width` attribute, it will limit how large the image can get. like so:

```
<div align="center" style="position:static; height: 100%; width: 100%; top:0;left 0;">
    <img src="myImg.png" style="width: 80%; max-width: 300px;">
</div>
```

You can make this `max-width` any size you want, as long as it doesn't exceed the actual width of the image. Also possible with height.

Answer (score -9):

```
class="img-thumbnail"
```

could be the solution.

Comment: Now "img-fluid" in Bootstrap 4

Comment: There is no indication that any framework is being used, let alone Bootstrap.